# Binding to StaticResource with a property of View Model in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have some custom fonts defined in ResourceDictionary

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Fonlow.VA.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="SuperFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Super.ttf#Super" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Super.ttf#Super" />
            <!--<On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Bold" />-->
        </OnPlatform>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="NormalFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Normal.ttf#Normal" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Normal.ttf#Normal" />
            <!--<On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Bold" />-->
        </OnPlatform>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And

```
  <Label Text="{Binding CurrentOptotype.Text}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SuperFont}" FontSize="{Binding CurrentFontSize}" TextColor="Black" />
```

So far so good. However, I would switch the FontFamily at runtime through ViewModel binding just like the binding for FontSize, since CurrentFontSize is a property in the View Model.
I had tried:

```
FontFamily="{Binding CurrentFontFamily}"
```

And the value of CurrentFontFamily can point to an existing system font, but I want to point to a custom font pointing to what defined in ResourceDictionary.

I had then tried:

```
FontFamily="{StaticResource {Binding CurrentFontFamily}}"
```

And there's runtime error obviously against such makeup syntax. I just wonder whether there's a in XAML to switch custom font at runtime through MVVM View Model?

Comment: I have not tried, but it's possible that `DynamicResource` would work in this case, instead of `StaticResource`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Trigger is the way to go, as explained in https://blog.xamarin.com/triggers-in-xamarin-forms/. Following the example there, now I have:

```
                    <Label Text="{Binding CurrentText}"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       FontSize="{Binding CurrentFontSize}" TextColor="Black"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                     Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference fontSelected}, Path=SelectedIndex}"
                                     Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource NormalFont}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                     Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference chartSelected}, Path=SelectedIndex}"
                                     Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SuperFont}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>

                    </Label.Triggers>
                </Label>
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this?

```
FontFamily="{Binding CurrentFontFamily}"
```

**Edit:**

You can do this with a converter :

```
public class FontConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var fontName = value as string;
        if(!Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(fontName))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"{fontName} not found in resources");
        return (string) Application.Current.Resources[fontName];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your App.xaml, add your converter :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ....
        <extensions:FontConverter x:Key="FontConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can bind your property

```
FontFamily={Binding FontName, Converter={StaticResource FontConverter}}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, this is not what I want, since this points to a concrete font name, not a custom font defined in the ResourceDctionary. So basically I want the binding point to the key of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

The `FontFamily="{Binding CurrentFontFamily}"` in the XAML is the way you're going to have to go about it. However, there's no reason the `CurrentFontFamily` property has to point to a system font. The Xamarin.Forms FontFamily property is just a string so there's no reason you shouldn't be able to do something like:

```
// previous code...
CurrentFontFamily = (whateverCondition == something)
    ? (string)Application.Current.Resources["SuperFont"]
    : (string)Application.Current.Resources["NormalFont"];
```